# Teradata: How can I convert a TIMESTAMP(6) field value to GMT?

Tags: timezone, teradata, gmt

I have a table with a column defined as `TIMESTAMP(6)`.  I need to do a mass conversion of all time values in this column from EST to GMT.  How do I go about this?

Comment: do you just need to add or subtract the same number of hours from each row?  are you concerned with daylight savings time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* EST is GMT -5:00:00 - To convert add 5 Hours to each timestamp */ 

select timestamp '2012-11-21 18:50:00' + interval '5:00:00' hour to second;
```

How you apply this to your data depends in part on how much data you are talking about. It may be easer to use a MERGE INTO SQL statement into an empty table and then rename the tables. If it is for display purposes only you can just use a view to accomplish the conversion.

Do you need to take into account Daylight Savings Time? The conversion might be a little trickier then.

Comment: Funny.  In Googling how to convert Eastern to GMT while taking DST into account, I came upon my own question!

Answer (score 0):

I did a little work around to compensate for DST, but it works well.  I am converting FROM UTC to Pacific and working in Teradata SQL Assist.

```
select
cast( a.strt_dt_tm as date) as BaseDt,
case 
when BaseDt <   '2018-03-11' then a.strt_dt_tm - interval '8:00:00' hour to second
when BaseDt>=  '2018-03-11' then a.strt_dt_tm - interval '7:00:00' hour to second
end as Offsetz,
cast(offsetz as date) as OffSt_Dt,
from Time_Table
```